# One-day bus ticket in Tartu

Tags: estonia

How can I buy and use an one-day bus ticket in Tartu, if that is an option?

I could not find that in https://tartu.pilet.ee/buy but I see its price in https://www.tartu.ee/en/ticket-prices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this on the [contactless bank cards FAQ](https://tartu.pilet.ee/pages/contactless-payments):

> **Which tickets can be bought?**
> One can only buy an hourly Tartu ticket (0,83 €) with a contactless bank card, one cannot buy a discount hourly ticket. *When you buy three or more hourly tickets during one day, the hourly tickets are automatically replaced with a one day ticket (€ 2.11)*.

(italics added for emphasis on the relevant part)

So if you are using a contactless card, then to buy a day ticket you simply buy a single ticket for each trip you take. When the total cost of the single tickets exceeds the cost of the day ticket, they are automatically replaced with a day ticket.

I would *imagine* the same applies if you are using the [bus card](https://tartu.ee/en/inner-city-bus-transportation#tartu-bus-card), although I haven't found any explicit confirmation of that.

Comment: I personally verified it and it is correct. Thanks!